# How to use droidAR in android application?

Tags: android, eclipse, augmented-reality

I try to use droidAR in my android AR project. I found an example from [here](http://parithi.com/2014/03/droidar-tutorial-getting-started-with-droidar/) and did all steps. I downloaded `droidar-master.zip` and extracted `C:/Documents`. I create a folder named WorkspaceAR under `C:/Documents`. I open eclipse on `WorkspaceAR`.

I run my test project as android application. Console message is below :

```
[2015-04-28 10:28:10 - TestProject] ------------------------------
[2015-04-28 10:28:10 - TestProject] Android Launch!
[2015-04-28 10:28:10 - TestProject] adb is running normally.
[2015-04-28 10:28:10 - TestProject] No Launcher activity found!
[2015-04-28 10:28:10 - TestProject] The launch will only sync the application package on the device!
[2015-04-28 10:28:10 - TestProject] Performing sync
[2015-04-28 10:28:10 - TestProject] Automatic Target Mode: Unable to detect device compatibility. Please select a target device.
[2015-04-28 10:29:04 - TestProject] Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.
[2015-04-28 10:29:04 - TestProject] \TestProject\bin\TestProject.apk installed on device
[2015-04-28 10:29:04 - TestProject] Done!
```

Screenshot of eclipse package explorer is here : 
[image]

AndroidMAnifets.xml of my project :

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

</application> 

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true" />
```

I run test project after my real device is attached to pc. But I don't see anything. The application doesn't start.

Comment: I think problem is because this apk is already installed on your device . Have you checked for it ?

Comment: I uninstall apk under `Settings->Apps->TestProject.apk`. I rerun on eclipse, but nothing changes.

Comment: can you please post your full AndroidManifest.xml .?

Comment: "Your code has many codes" is said. Please, use this link https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzattLnu9NhuLUR1dXVub1d1Vkk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: seems you don't have any Launcher activity.  http://parithi.com/2014/03/droidar-tutorial-getting-started-with-droidar/  has displayed full steps for how to integrate and test droidAr in your app please go through it step by step.

Comment: I did all steps. Maybe I failed to notice one step. But I don't aware of it.